# Update of the foreign key to a null value

Tags: php, sql

This query generates an error:

```
UPDATE sale 
SET NumFacture='Null',
WHERE Code='22'
```

Where `NumFacture` is a foreign key in table `sale` so I can't update it with Null value. How can I do please!

Comment: `'Null'` is a string literal, not a null value. Remove the quotes. And `'22'` is the text '22', not an integer.

Comment: Yes, Thank you, I forget it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try without single quotes:

```
UPDATE sale 
SET NumFacture=Null
WHERE Code='22'
```

Comment: Oh,I have not paid attention, Thank you